# Rsvg Convert not working with path text

Tags: imagemagick, librsvg, rsvg

I'm trying to parse an svg file to png format.

This is my svg file: https://cdn-imgs-p.stackprint.net/spree/images/62398/original/preview_01.svg

When using  `rsvg-convert --unlimited preview_01.svg > preview.png`, the paths fonts are not being converted properly:

This is my output png file: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/carga-masiva/preview.png

I don't know if this is a bug, or there is a workaround to make it work.

My rsvg-version is `2.40.19`

Comment: This command using Imagemagick with RSVG 2.42.2_0 fails with an abort trap. convert preview_01.svg preview_01.png`. Try using Inkscape. If Inkscape does not work. Then perhaps your SVG file is corrupt.

Comment: Didnt know that 2.42.2 exists. I' trying with 2.40.19 and 2.40.13 and no errors in the output. Seems like librsvg is not supporting strokes in path

Comment: can you try inkscape

Comment: fmw42 you're like an angel for me. This works with inkscape, i would like to know if there is a librsvg solution for it

Comment: All I can suggest is try the latest version of librsvg. If that does not work, then contact them about your issue. Perhaps they will fix librsvg in their next release.